# A test runs well in Eclipse but fails in Maven

Tags: java, maven, testng, mockito, jboss-arquillian

I have a TestNG test in a maven Java EE web application project running on JBoss WildFly 8.

When I run the test with TestNG Eclipse plug-in it runs fine, but when I'm building the maven project with test with " mvn clean install "

I get the following test failure:

Failed tests:   mockTestDifferentBrands(com.myProject.mytestNGTest) arquillianAfterClass(com.myProject.mytestNGTest): Could not initialize class org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil

I tried to update PowerMock version, did " Update Maven Project " in eclipse, cleaned and refreshed project and I still get that. Any ideas what might cause it? Thank you.

Comment: Could you post your pom?

Answer (score 0):

The last mockito version that properly works with powermock is 1.10.8.
The incompatibility between mockito and powermock generate error like yours. Maybe you should check this thread : https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=524

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an indicator that you are referencing wrong version of a library in your pom (Mockito in test scope here, I assume).

Check the versions of Mockito used when running in Eclipse and with Maven, if they differ, update your pom accordingly.